# Add ringtones in android emulator

Tags: android, emulation, ringtone

Does anyone know how to add/download a ringtone or an mp3 sound to an android emulator?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to `DDMS` in `Eclipse`, click the `File Explorer` tab and navigate to `mnt/sdcard`. Create a new folder by clicking the `Plus` icon called `ringtones`. Then click on the`"Push a file on to the device"` icon and choose your file.

You may need to restart the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

From Eclipse:

Click on `Window -> Open Perspective -> DDMS`

*Note: First start the emulator, so its contents will be available under File Explorer*

Now click on the `File Explorer` tab and navigate to `mnt/sdcard`.

If this directory already has a directory named `ringtones` then navigate to it, or else create a new directory named `mnt/sdcard/ringtones`.

*Note: To create a new directory, you need to click on "+" (plus) icon in the top right corner*

To upload the ringtones files click on `Push a file on to device`, again in the top right corner, and upload the ringtones. After that you need to restart Eclipse as well as the emulator.